# Need to compare the feature of two annotations which having same index position-UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I have two annotations named First and Second.In this I need to  compare the feature of two annotations which having same index position.

**First.csv:**

```
    Position1;0
    Position2;1
```

**Script:**

```
  DECLARE Second(INT secondpass); 
  "Position1"->Second;

  WORDTABLE FirstList = 'First.csv';
  DECLARE Annotation First(INT firstpass);
  Document{->MARKTABLE(First, 2, FirstList,true,0,"",0, "firstpass" = 1 )};

  DECLARE Text;
     p1:First ANY*? p2:Second{p1.secondpass == p2.firstpass -> MARK(Text)};
```

**p1:First # p2:Second{p1.secondpass == p2.firstpass -> MARK(Text)};** wont work because both annotations are in same positions.

Comment: You probably mixed up the indexes in MARKTABLE. It should maybe read `Document{->MARKTABLE(First, 1, FirstList,true,0,"",0, "firstpass" = 2 )};`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how exactly the offsets need to be checked, something like the following would probably do:

```
p1:First{-> MARK(Text)}<-{p2:Second{p1.begin==p2.begin,p1.end==p2.end,p1.firstpass==p2.secondpass};};
```

or

```
p1:First{p1.firstpass == Second.secondpass -> MARK(Text)};
```

You can specify this also with a conjunct rule element (`&`), but I would recommend to avoid these if not really necessary.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*